# JKS file location in android studio is not updated

Tags: android, android-studio, jks, signed-apk

I am using a windows 10 OS. I had the jks file in desktop. Then i gave the path to the file and built a signed apk. It was fine. Then i moved the jks file to another location. When I tried to build a signed apk, I gave the new location in the dialogue window. But the build failed. The message said, jks file was not found in desktop. Why android studio is still looking for the file in desktop even after changing the location? Should I change the path in some other place too?

Answer (score 0):

If I were in a similar situation I would invalidate cache and restart first, then when building signed apk I would give keystore path again by clicking "Choose existing..." and proceed.